# PDO wrong bindings with Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, pdo, eloquent, query-builder

I have a search query that works perfect (I stripped some unimportant code):

```
$posts = new Post;

if(Input::has('query')) {
    // Search for posts with title or tags matching the given criteria
    $posts = $posts
        ->addSelect(DB::raw("MATCH(posts.title) AGAINST (?) as post_score"))
        ->addSelect(DB::raw("MATCH(tags.title) AGAINST (?) as tag_score"))
        ->where(function($query) {
            return $query
                ->whereRaw('MATCH(posts.title) AGAINST (?)')
                ->orWhereRaw('MATCH(tags.title) AGAINST (?)');
        })
        ->orderBy(DB::raw('post_score+tag_score'), 'desc')
        ->setBindings([ $input['query'], $input['query'], $input['query'], $input['query'] ]);
}
```

But as soon as I add this piece of code before the above `if()` statement:

```
if(Input::has('filter')) {
    $posts = $posts->whereType($input['filter']); //Filter type by either 'article' or 'question'
}
```

... I get this error:

```
[2014-11-04 19:28:18] production.ERROR: PDO error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: select `posts`.*, COALESCE(SUM(post_votes.rating), 0) as rating, MATCH(posts.title) AGAINST (css) as post_score, MATCH(tags.title) AGAINST (css) as tag_score from `posts` left join `post_tags` on `post_tags`.`post_id` = `posts`.`id` left join `tags` on `tags`.`id` = `post_tags`.`tag_id` left join `post_votes` on `post_votes`.`post_id` = `posts`.`id` where `type` = css and (MATCH(posts.title) AGAINST (css) or MATCH(tags.title) AGAINST (?)) group by `posts`.`id` order by post_score+tag_score desc, `views` desc) [] []
```

I entered `css` as search query, the type should be filtered on `question`. As you can see the variables aren't binded right (don't know the right word for this). How could this be? I also tried this which doesn't work:

```
->where(function($query) use ($input) {
    return $query
        ->whereRaw('MATCH(posts.title) AGAINST (?)', [$input['query']])
        ->orWhereRaw('MATCH(tags.title) AGAINST (?)', [$input['query']]);
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
if(Input::has('filter')) {
  $posts->whereType($input['filter']); //Filter type by either 'article' or 'question'
}

if(Input::has('query')) {
  // no need for this:
  // $posts = $posts
  // just:
  $posts
    ->addSelect(DB::raw("MATCH(posts.title) AGAINST (?) as post_score"))
    ->addBinding($input['query'], 'select')
    ->addSelect(DB::raw("MATCH(tags.title) AGAINST (?) as tag_score"))
    ->addBinding($input['query'], 'select')
    ->where(function($query) use ($input) {
       $query
         ->whereRaw('MATCH(posts.title) AGAINST (?)', [$input['query']])
         ->orWhereRaw('MATCH(tags.title) AGAINST (?)', [$input['query']]);
    })
    ->orderBy(DB::raw('post_score+tag_score'), 'desc')
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfect! The only thing is, I need `$posts = $posts->(...)` in order to get it working. Just `$posts->(...)` isn't doing it for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JasonK What error do you get? I'm positive you don't need to do `$posts = $posts->...`, since you operate on the Builder object.

Comment: Yes you're right, now it does work. I only need to do `$posts = $posts->select('posts.*')` in the beginning. If I don't do this, the search query isn't working good (but no errors).

Comment: True, if you still need all the fields, then you need that `select` first.

Comment: `->addSelect(DB::raw("MATCH(tags.title) AGAINST (?) as tag_score"))
->addBinding($input['query'], 'select')`
   is equivalent to
`->selectRaw("MATCH(tags.title) AGAINST (?) as tag_score", $input['query'])`.